# Python 3 - Tkinter - askopenfilename - Filter filenames trough regEx (Not by extension)

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to filter the filenames we see when we browse for a file using tkinter askopenfilename ?
I don't need to filter by extension, but by a specific pattern in the filename.

For example I have hundred of files in one folder, most named "Chapter_XXX - Title" and only one file named "Book". I would like to display only the files that start with Book.

Is such a thing possible?

Thanks Martin, that worked. These type of examples should be included in the documentation.

The code I needed:

```
fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("Books","Book*.*"),("All files","*.*")))
```

Comment: why not use `glob` ?

Comment: or you could use the `filetype` arguments to define specific filter like `(required files,book*.*)`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Also didn't know about glob, looks interesting, but can't really see how to combine it with askopenfilename.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like the extension, you can define strings that should be contained in the filename using the `filetypes`argument.

So, analogous to the extension tuple `('Excel Spreadsheet','.xlsx')`, you can specify to get all .xlsx-files, you can define `('Book Files','book*.*')`. This would result in a list where the string `"book"` appears anywhere in the filename.

Comment: I was working with this last night, and if I didn't include `("any file", "*.*")` it threw an exception. Something about a "bad Mac extension" or something similar. You may want to include that in your answer. To be clear, I use windows, and I still got that error.

Comment: I would not use `*.*` as the part before the extension is set to an asterisk, anyway. You'll get `**.*` as search string, which will not work. Just use `("any file", ".*")`